# Update DOM after insert in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say I use jQuery to load new content into a specific DIV element. If I now want to catch events from inside that DIV element, I assume the DOM has to be updated somehow? What is the best way to deal with this?

Edit: Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".edit").click(function(){
          $(this).parent().load("edit");
        });
        $(".view").click(function(){
          $(this).parent().load("view");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='someid'>
      <input type='submit' class='edit' value='Edit'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

where a file `edit` at the same level contains

```
<input type='submit' class='view' value='View'>
```

and a file 'view' contains

```
<input type='submit' class='edit' value='Edit'>
```

If you try this out you will see that when you first press Edit, the button changes to View, but then it doesn't change anymore. Why is this?

Comment: If you load new content into a DIV element, that *is* the same thing as updating the DOM, isn't it?

Comment: I mean that if I use e.g. $(this).load('getcontent') and that content contains new DIV elements with new IDs that weren't defined before, I can't seem to select those new elements with jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) like this:

```
 $(".view").live("click",function(){
      $(this).parent().load("view");
    });
```

Answer (score 22):

Since jQuery 1.7.x the **.live()** method is deprecated. Use **.on()** to attach event handlers. If you are using an older version you should use **.delegate()** in preference to **.live()**.

As mentioned in the help, the format does not change a lot like shown in this example:

> $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
>   $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
>   $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

So since 1.7.x, both, **delegate** and **live** have been superseeded by **on**.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses "[live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)" events to deal with things happening in dynamically added DOM elements without having to manually add handlers after a content-update.

Comment: I've added an example to my original post to show what the problem is