# When is the DOM ready after a jQuery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 project making an ajax call that returns HTML that I can successfully inject into the page. However I have a problem in hiding a CSS class after the code has been injected.  I suspect that the DOM is not ready.

I am aware that the document ready function *$(function () {...}* is only called when the page is loaded initially - and I don't want to call it again anyway - so I was wondering if there is another method that can be used after an ajax call to determine when the DOM is ready.

This is the ajax code:

```
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/seoreports/seoupdate',
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html",
                data: JSON.stringify(dt),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#seolist').html(result);
                    if (ptshow == false) { $('.seo-pt').hide(); }
                }
            });
```

The idea is that if the *ptshow* variable is false it hides all the divs with the class *seo-pt* after the HTML has been injected.

I did try, just for testing, to put *alert('hello world');* in the success function, but that didn't work so maybe there is something I'm not understanding about the success function.

Comment: Is the request definitely getting to the server? Use something like firebug in Firefox and track the request.

Comment: If the success function is not alerting hello world something else is wrong. Have a look under the network tab, does it fail? What does the console say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550761/update-dom-after-insert-in-jquery   check this

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`? Why wouldn't `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` work for you?

Comment: The request is definitely getting to the server and the HTML is being injected correctly - the browser display is correct.  I went around the problem (because I couldn't spend more time on it) and used an MVC Ajax.ActionLink call: @Ajax.ActionLink("LC", "seolist", new { lc= ViewBag.lc, so = "lang" }, new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "seolist", OnSuccess="ajaxSuccess('lang')"}). This works just fine but this 'answer' doesn't merit points, so I put it here.

Answer (score 0):

the success function is the correct place for your code to go. Without more code to look at, it is very difficult to say why your call is failing. Also, You should add a handler for the error function as well, that may tell you why your alert was not hit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: '/seoreports/seoupdate',
type: "POST",
async:false,
...
...
```

Try this....everything will wait for the compleation of the call, but that may be ok in your case, and you may have better control over what happens next