# How to get ID value of first element with specific class in html by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
    <div id="calc_pol_list">
       <li class="calc_li">
           <span class="right_list_number">1</span>
           <p id="120" class="calc_p"/>
       </li>
       <li class="calc_li">
           <span class="right_list_number">2</span>
           <p id="100" class="calc_p"/>
       </li>
    </div>
```

I need to get ID of first p:  with jQuery and convert this ID to string.

I've tried this code:

```
    $('#calc_pol_list p:first').attr('id');
```

But it doesn't works.

How can I do this?

UPDATE:
Here is my function:

```
function refreshCost(){
    if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
        stomCost = parseInt($('div#calc_pol_list calc_p:first').attr('id'));
        var cost = stomCost + scatCost + polCost;               
        $("#pre_cost").text(cost);
    };
};
```

Yes, my code is correct, if considered separately from the rest of the code. I realized what the problem is, but I do not know how to solve it. The problem is that these

I add after the Ajax request that is not in their original DOM. The form, which owns these

is inside the div. I read here that I need to make the form a direct child of the body, but in this case it's impossible.

Comment: it should work, if it is executed after dom ready [working](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NVg5G/1/) - [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NVg5G/2/)

Comment: your code seems to be working fine..

Comment: works ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/BfUbV/

Comment: id attribute should not begin with a number `" ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")"` [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html)

Comment: Yes, my code is correct, if considered separately from the rest of the code. I realized what the problem is, but I do not know how to solve it.

The problem is that these <p> I add after the Ajax request that is not in their original DOM. The form, which owns these <p> is inside the div. I read [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/reload-dom-after-injecting-form-elements) that I need to make the form a direct child of the body, but in this case it's impossible.

Comment: I found another discussion of this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550761/update-dom-after-insert-in-jquery), but I do not understand how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Here is the function which I need to run after Ajax request:
`function refreshCost(){
 if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
  stomCost = parseInt($('div#calc_pol_list calc_p:first').attr('id'));
  var cost = stomCost + scatCost + polCost;    
  $("#pre_cost").text(cost);
 };
};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to use .ajaxStop

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    alert($('#calc_pol_list p').eq(0).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#calc_pol_list p').first().attr('id')
```

like this :)

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
$('#calc_pol_list p').eq(0).attr('id');
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/ppzqx/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
alert($('#calc_pol_list p:first').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

See: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and get variable in it e.g.

```
var content = $('#calc_pol_list > li p:first').attr('id');
```

and alert it you will get id as string e.g.

```
alert (content );
```

Comment: Please format code blocks by using (a) 4 space indenting or (b) selecting the code block and clicking on `{}` button in button bar or (c) selecting code block and clicking Ctrl + K. Formatted code makes the answer easier to read :)